# Ext js problem - unable to inherit "has-many" by extending model

Tags: extjs, extjs7

**Good evening everyone,**

I am facing a problem with Ext Js (7.2) model inheritance.
I would need to create a model and extend it by inheriting the has-many property of the parent.
I noticed though that the model it extends doesn't see that property, has anyone by chance solved this problem or know how I could overcome it?

I attach an example of the problem encountered.

Example:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3c0h

**Thanks to everyone.**

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines of code to solve your issue given below :

```
var postStore = store.data.items[0].data.posts;
Ext.Msg.alert('Post', '' + postStore.length + '-' +postStore[0].title, Ext.emptyFn);
```

Comment: Good morning, thank you for your reply but it is not what I am looking for. My need is to retrieve the property "hasMany" from the "MyApp.model.User" in the "MyApp.model.UserExtend".With the proposed solution it takes the information from the store and not from the model, also it would not work with model 'MyApp.model.User'.